# Как правильно хранить список пользователей подключенных к серверу

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть сокет сервер на JS. К нему подключены пользователи. Сейчас они лежат в массиве. У некоторых пользователей есть ключи на других пользователей с которыми они переписываются, короче чат. Мне казалось это идеальный вариант пока не понял что пользователей надо удалять. А при удалении ключи сдвигаются, или создается пустая ячейка. Как можно по другому реализовать. Может обьектом как-то ? Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объектом. Как то так:

```
Users = {
  *userId*: {
     name: *name*,
     chats: {
        *chatId*: [*userId*, *userId*, ...],
        *chatId*: [*userId*, *userId*, ...],
        ...
     }
  },
  ...
}
```

Удалять пользователей и чаты можно соответственно так:

```
delete Users[userId];
delete Users.chats[chatId];
```

Comment: А как указывать ссылки на обьекты, и удалять их ?

Comment: ну создаете уникальные идентификаторы для пользователей, вот вам и ключи. Удаление из объекта тоже просто делается